# How store the textures in a .dll library?

Tags: c#, dll, xna-4.0

Hy guys, I am new to XNA, just player around with it for like two weeks. C# is also quite new for me, I`ve used Visual Basic, but I just decided to learn XNA basics, because of the slow GDI+. I want to make a Media app, which has a lot of texture images (multiple menu styles, multiple built-in backgrounds, etc.), and the fact that all of these files is located in the Content folder on the hard drive, is kinda messy :D . Is there any way to create a separate library for the GUI and store the textures in a .dll file just like in WinForms? It looks so ugly when the textures can be seen outside the application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help : [(MSDN) Loading Content Within a Game Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604975.aspx)